# Can Zookeeper remain highly available if one of three nodes fails

Tags: apache-zookeeper, high-availability

If I have three zookeeper nodes, one leader and two followers. What happens if the leader dies? Would the new leader be selected from the remaining two? If so, what happens if the new leader also dies? Would the last one still serve clients?

Comment: Hi @Jack, do you use a supervisory process to manage your zookeepers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a ZooKeeper cluster, if a leader dies the other remaining nodes will elect a leader among themselves. This will usually be very quick and there should be no visible outage to the clients. The clients that were connected to the leader that died will reconnect to one of the other nodes.

As for the second question - in a 3 node cluster, if 2 of the nodes die, the third one will not be serving requests. The reason for that is that the one remaining node cannot know if it is in fact the only survivor or if it has been partitioned off from others. Continuing to serve request at that point could cause a split brain scenario and violate the core ZooKeeper guarantee.

Comment: Thanks Igorbel, I still have question: in three ZK nodes, if the leader dead, will the remaining two nodes still working? if work, how do they elect the new leader since it's a even quorum.

Comment: Yes, the 2 remaining nodes will elect a leader. This is a guarantee of the ZooKeeper protocol. The reason why this works is that they both know there is a 3rd member of the cluster, it just doesn't appear to be up at the moment. It is not the same as if you initially started a 2 node cluster.

Comment: Thank you! But how do the remaining two nodes elect themselves, since it's a even number the votes maybe equal.

Comment: Oh, good point. Don't worry about that. Unlike politicians, ZooKeeper nodes will be able to reach consensus even if there are only 2 of them. You can check in more detail how it works here, but basically the Liveness of the protocol is guaranteed in all cases: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperInternals.html#sc_leaderElection

Comment: @igorbel , in case we have 20 kafka machine , what you think should be the number of zookeeper in the cluster?